# I making plugin where i wanna create option for user to choose color of badge, and have problem with calling it in css,didnt working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

My main php file free-shipping-badge.php

```
/** REGISTER STYLES **/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fsb_stylesheet' );
function fsb_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'view-style', plugins_url('/view/fsb_badge_style.php', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'view-style' );
}

/** ADD FREE SHIPPING BADGE SUFFIX AFTER PRICE **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'fsb_suffix', 99, 4 );
function fsb_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $fsb_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Regular price
    $fsb_limit_price = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_limit_price_option') ); // Limit price
    $fsb_badge_text = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_badge_text_option') ); // Text to display on badge
    $fsb_badge_color = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_badge_color_option') ); // Text to display on badge
    if($fsb_price > $fsb_limit_price){
    $html .='</br>'.'<fsb_badge class="fsb_badge_view">' .$fsb_badge_text.' '.'</fsb_badge>';
    return $html;
}
}
```

My style file:fsb_badge_style.php. Background did not get value from php variable $fsb_badge_color and it is main problem.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
include('free-shipping-badge.php');     
?>
.fsb_badge_view{
    display: inline;
    padding: .3em .6em .3em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: middle;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
    background-color:  <?php echo $fsb_badge_color; ?>;

}
```

Comment: I've never seen a .php file enqueued via `wp_register_style()`.  My recommendation would be to assign the `background-color:` value via jQuery and using script localization to pass the value.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

Answer (score 2):

As @Tony Djukic said you can't enqueue a PHP file as a style sheet, it won't process the PHP. Something that is possible though is outputting the style inline in the header. An example:

```
function fsb_badge_style()
{
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\">.fsb_badge_view{background-color: ".$fsb_badge_color.";}</style>";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'fsb_badge_style', 100);
```

This will write the style directly in the header.

```
<style type="text/css">.fsb_badge_view{background-color: #e7e7e7;}</style>
```

As an added bonus this will also work for users that may not have JavaScript enabled.